# AJAX response undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I've checked various posts on this subject and I can't see why I'm getting undefined still for responseText. The returned json should look like {"token": "ghargaeorigjaoregrjarjegijra[pgjpraejgprjgpkfp5p34i5483te8q9rut053"}

```
function getAuth(username, password) {

    let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url, method;
    let data = {"username": username, "password": password};

    url = returnLocation("default");
    method = 'POST';

    http.open(method, "http://" + url + "/monitor/admin/auth/", true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    http.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    http.send(JSON.stringify(data));

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (http.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && http.status === 200){
            setCookie(http.responseText);
        }
        else if (http.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && http.status !== 200){
            alert(http.statusText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in cases like this I recommend to log the object (in your case `http`) in the console using `console.log(http)` to find out if there is an attribute named "responseText"

Comment: Do you get the value undefined from http.responseText, or do you get an error "unable to access property responseText of undefined" or similar.

Comment: I try to JSON.parse and get undefined. When I log console.log(http.responseText) I get undefined.

Logging the http object I get:


onabort: nullresponse: "{"token":"redacted"}"
responseText: "{"token":"redacted"}"

Comment: So I have the response I just can't process it.

Comment: Thanks for the troubleshooting tip, when you're stuck sometimes you go blank and I'm deploying django in a docker container which makes it a little tougher.

I used response instead of repsonseText. Works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I've used the http.response instead of http.ResponseText